# Calculate Field python code has "Expected end of statement" error

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I am creating a line shapefile from a csv in a Python (2.7) script. I am assigning an ID field from the csv to a variable and then later using it in the **Calculate Field** tool. The ID field originally looks like this '011947-OCT-084' which ArcGIS(10.1) does not seem to like, so I removed the '-'s and when I use that variable in the tool I get an error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Expected end of statement
>   Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Here is my code ("temp" is the shapefile temporarily stored in in_memory):

```
with open(inCSV, 'rb') as input:
    with open(outCSV, 'wb') as output:
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(output, headers, delimiter = ',')
        csvwriter.writeheader()
        for row in csv.DictReader(input):
            uniqueID = row['Common_id']
            newID = uniqueID.replace("-", "")
            arcpy.AddField_management("temp", "uniqueID", "TEXT")
            arcpy.CalculateField_management("temp", "uniqueID", newID)
            row['Common_id'] = newID
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

I'm not entirely sure what the cause behind this is, as I've used variables in the Calculate Tool field before without a problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("temp", "uniqueID", repr(newID), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

The default language is VBA, so need to specify that, and `newID` probably isn't properly quoted as a Python expression so `repr()` will take care of that.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm not sure I've ever heard of the repr() function, but this will come in handy a lot!